# Converting hex to decimal in C

Tags: c, hex

For example, when

```
val = 0x505050
val1 = 0x005000
```

The result should be the addtion of the two hexadecimals, which is:

```
0x50a050
```

What I did is:

```
int hex;
int channel;
int result;

printf("first hex number: ");
scanf("%x", &hex);

printf("second hex number: ");
scanf("%x", &channel);

result = hex + channel;
printf("Your new hex value is: ");
printf("0x%x\n", result);
```

And this brought me the right result. However, the problem here is that, when the second (channel) value is like,

```
50 00 00
```

it is base 10, not 16 so the addition of 0x505050 and 50 00 00 should be 0x825050 but I get 0x5050a0.

How can I manage this problem?
Also, when the second input is not hex and it is negative, for example,

```
-50 -40 -30
```

I get 0x505000, but it should be 0x1e2832

How can handle with negative numbers?

Can someone please help me out with this problem?

Comment: `50` as well as `00` are valid hexadecimal numbers. You can't catch them unless you read the whole line as text and attempt to parse the string manually. As for invalid numbers, see what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*.

Comment: How do you feed inputs to your program? Are you aware that if you read `"50 00 00"` with `scanf("%x", ...)` only the first number is read?

Comment: You can use `strtol` with a base of `0` to convert the strings to numbers. It will (for example) interpret the string `"0x500"` as a hexadecimal number and the string `"500"` as a decimal number. Before using `strtol`, you would need to read the user's input into as a string using either `fgets` or `scanf` with a format of `"%s"`.

Comment: @Scheff Oh right, I didn't count the bytes very carefully there :) Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to gather your input as text, and then go through logic of your own creation to figure out if the text should be interpreted as base16, base10, or something else:

```
char input[1024];
fgets(input, 1024, stdin);
// Examine input to figure out if base16, or base10.
```

---

You also wrote that `500000(base10) + 0x505050(base16)` should be `0x825050(base16)`.  But when I add those together, I get `0x57F170(base16)`.
Please clarify your math?

Comment: It should cover under and over flows.... I also get that hex value as you wrote but it says it should be 0x825050..